# Drop down menu disappears on hovering over first option (blogger)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue with a drop down menu - and must admit, I'm new to coding. The drop down menu disappears when hovering just below the text within the first drop down menu option box itself, so it's definitely a spacing issue.

I have looked all over Stack overflow and elsewhere. The fixes I've seen entail decreasing the "top" or "top-margin" value. This didn't work for me. The "top" value is currently set at 45, but when I decreased it, the drop down options just moved up higher, over the main menu itself.. and kept disappearing upon hover. 
Here's the site: http://www.salimapirani.com 
The code is quite long but I can include it if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add below style :

`.tabs-inner .widget ul#icbabdrop li ul {
     z-index: 1;
   }`[image]

Comment: thank you! I changed it to 
z-index: 10000; 
padding-top: 40px
and it worked great. Thanks again. Neat imaging you got there too.

Comment: your welcome :) please accept my answer if you think it's useful :)